# Karate JUNIT 5 not running on command line maven

Tags: maven, karate, junit5

I am new to Karate and I recently created a project that runs well on Intellij Idea, however, when executing using maven command line tests do not run, please see details below:

```
   maven Command used:

    mvn -Dtest=ExamplesTest -DfailIfNoTests=false test -U
    mvn -Dtest=ExamplesTest test
    mvn test
```

Results:

Running automation.tests.uiTests.UsersRunner
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.301 s - in automation.tests.uiTests.UsersRunner

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Test runner file:

```
    package automation;

    import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
    import com.intuit.karate.Results;
    import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;
    import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
    import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;



    class ExamplesTest {


        @Test
        void testParallel() {
            Results results=Runner.path("classpath:karateTests").parallel(2);
            assertEquals(0,results.getFailCount(),results.getErrorMessages());
            generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        }
        public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
            Collection jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
            List jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
            jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "TestAutomation");
            ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
            reportBuilder.generateReports();
        }


    }
```

```
POM:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId><ProjectName></artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <karate.version>1.0.1</karate.version>
    </properties>    

    <dependencies>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>        
    </build>       

</project>
```

intelij version:

Intellij Idea Version:

```
    IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.5787.30, built on May 31, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.15+10-b2043.56 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
```

Comment: Edit your post the pom content is not readable.. etc. Recheck it..

Comment: agree with above comment. read these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and let me say that unless you follow this process, I don't think anyone can help you: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I have edited the POM and will go through the link above. Thank you!

Comment: Upgrade maven surefire plugin version and make sure tests are in `src/test/java` folder